# Get hold of variable value combining two strings

Tags: python, class, list-comprehension

I would like to have dynamic parameters for a API I'm using.
For that I'm searching for a easy way to achieve the following:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.search_param_list = [from, to]
    self.from = A
    self.to = B

def search_params2(self):
    parameters = {parameter: self.parameter for parameter in self.search_param_list}
    return parameters
```

The output is expected to look something like this:

```
parameters ={"from": A, "to": B}
```

I do this to change the params in the init if wanted, but that I don't have to do it if not necessary.

Comment: The way you've defined `__init__()` it takes no arguments at all, so I don't understand how you expect to pass any parameters in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` is an illegal variable name. Use `from_` or something else.

Save the names to be searched as strings.

Access instance attributes via string-name with `getattr`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.from_ = 2
        self.to = 3
        self.search_param_list = ['from_', 'to']

    def search_params2(self):
        return {p: getattr(self, p) for p in self.search_param_list}
```

Demo:

```
>>> A().search_params2()
{'from_': 2, 'to': 3}
```

---

Of course, you can get all instance variables immediately with `vars`.

```
>>> vars(A())
{'x': 1, 'from_': 2, 'to': 3, 'search_param_list': ['from_', 'to']}
```

Comment: Note that `from` is an illegal *identifier*, but it can still be used as an attribute name. If you'll be using `getattr` anyway, you might consider using `setattr(self, 'from', 2)` instead.

Comment: @chepner I'd rather not.